# What packages do I need to add the functionality of NodeZero?

Tags: package-management, custom-distributions

[NodeZero](http://www.nodezero-linux.org/) is a distribution optimized for

> Penetration testing and security auditing specialist tools
>
> NodeZero comes around 300 tools for penetration testing and set of basic services which are needed in penetration testing.

Which packages exactly are installed there by default, that are'nt on Ubuntu Desktop? Or how can I find out?

Answer (score 1):

- copy the NodeZero ISO file on a USB Stick with Unetbootin
- start from the stick
- `dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | cut -f 1 > /tmp/dpkg-list.nodezero`
  (see [How to list all installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages))

Here is the result: [All packages in NodeZero](https://gist.github.com/rubo77/02586661881c1d67e1c9)

```
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rubo77/02586661881c1d67e1c9/raw/eeaa10503909185151c20659177dc897076e0b59/nodezero%20package%20list -q -O - \
> /tmp/dpkg-list.nodezero
```

[Which packages are installed on Ubuntu desktop by default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548085/which-packages-are-installed-on-ubuntu-desktop-by-default)

```
 wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.04.3/ubuntu-10.04-desktop-amd64.manifest \
   -q -O - | cut -f 1 > /tmp/dpkg-list.ubuntu-10.04
```

Now compare those files with

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next} !($1 in a) {print $1, $4}' \
/tmp/dpkg-list.ubuntu-10.04 /tmp/dpkg-list.nodezero \
> /tmp/diff-packages
```

I filtered those packages by libs and standard apps that are not relevant here:

```
egrep  -v '(lib|gstreamer|xserver|x11|ttf|python|openoffice|gnome|firefox|evolution)' /tmp/diff-packages
```

to get [this list of packages that are in NodeZero but not in Ubuntu 10.04](https://gist.github.com/rubo77/bd9183fe2794467f482c)

TODO: [Identify packages and dependencies](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167215/identify-packages-and-dependencies)