# Which packages are installed on Ubuntu desktop by default?

Tags: package-management

Is there a list of packages that are installed on a fresh install?

I know, there is the other question [How do I list the default installed packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48886/how-do-i-list-the-default-installed-packages) But that doesn't show, what will be the output of

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | cut -f 1
```

right after a fresh install of Ubuntu desktop?

I would like to compare the resulting remaining list with the packages I have installed at the moment, so I can find out, what changed on the system since install.

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/a/492343/34298 which uses `/var/log/installer/initial-status.gz`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a full list in the manifest file of each distribution at: https://releases.ubuntu.com

To get just the list use:

```
wget https://releases.ubuntu.com/utopic/ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.manifest \
-q -O - | cut -f 1
```

Note: not all these packages stay installed. The CD images contain a list of things to remove after installation, in a file called `/capsper/filesystem.manifest-remove`. ([here](https://gist.github.com/rubo77/1d368cc20cec4ede39e917a8a2b9e4fc) is this file from Ubuntu 17.10)

Related: [check if all default packages are installed from the Ubuntu manifest](https://askubuntu.com/a/588161)