# What is SSH-Add and why is it installed in my Kubuntu?

Tags: server, ssh, kubuntu

Currently it is listed under 'Internet' however clicking it does absolutely nothing.

Running '**ps aux | grep sshd**' results in:

```
kdenoob     3867  0.0  0.0  14224  1016 pts/1    S+   14:12   0:00 grep --color=auto sshd
```

Running '**service sshd status**' results in:

```
    ● sshd.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

So this doesn't seem to be SSH server running by default like Fedora did a few weeks back right? What is the point of SSH-Add and why is that only Kubuntu seems to have it installed but none of the other Ubuntu flavors do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Fedora, ssh server is not installed by default with K/ubuntu.

You can check the default packages by checking the manifest list - see [check if all default packages are installed from the Ubuntu manifest](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588145/check-if-all-default-packages-are-installed-from-the-ubuntu-manifest)

Or here - http://releases.ubuntu.com/

Go to a release / version http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/17.04/release/

click the manifest http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/17.04/release/kubuntu-17.04-desktop-amd64.manifest

ssh-add is part of (open)ssh client and manages keys

https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/openssh-client

openssh-clinet is installed by default on all versions of ubuntu as far as I know

See https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/openssh-client

Comment: Thank you, I know I've seen that name around here! That completely solves my question 100%. You rock!